# How to use webview to open url just like UCBrowser

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new in android. I am trying to make just a sample application to open websites in webview. The problem is, website opens in desktop mode. How can I open websites just like UCBrowser (mobile mode) ?

Comment: what is mean by like UCBrowser ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: String android = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
webview1.getSettings().setUserAgentString(android);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    webview1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview1 .loadUrl("http://www.matrixsystems.net.in/");  // set url
    webview1.requestFocus();
```